# Parsing structured syslog with syslog-ng

Tags: syslog-ng

I am trying to leverage the parsing of structured data feature in `syslog-ng`. From my firewall, I am forwarding the following message:

> <14>1 2012-10-06T11:03:56.493 SRX100 RT_FLOW - RT_FLOW_SESSION_CLOSE [junos@2636.1.1.1.2.36 reason="TCP FIN" source-address="192.168.199.207" source-port="59292" destination-address="184.73.190.157" destination-port="80" service-name="junos-http" nat-source-address="50.193.12.149" nat-source-port="19230" nat-destination-address="184.73.190.157" nat-destination-port="80" src-nat-rule-name="source-nat-rule" dst-nat-rule-name="None" protocol-id="6" policy-name="trust-to-untrust" source-zone-name="trust" destination-zone-name="untrust" session-id-32="9375" packets-from-client="9" bytes-from-client="4342" packets-from-server="7" bytes-from-server="1507" elapsed-time="1" application="UNKNOWN" nested-application="UNKNOWN" username="N/A" roles="N/A" packet-incoming-interface="vlan.0"]

Based on the format of the IETF logs, it appears to be correct, but for some reason the structured data is actually being parsed as the message portion of the log and not being parsed as structured data.

Answer (score 1):

On the syslog-ng side, you need to use either a syslog() source, or a tcp() source with flags(syslog-proto) set, and then the stuff will end up in variables like ${.SDATA.junos@2636.1.1.1.2.36.reason} and so on and so forth, which then you can use as you see fit.